# Ubuntu 20.04 slow boot time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ssd, grub

From a "minimal" fresh desktop install of Ubuntu 20.04 (not a system / distro upgrade), I have very slow boot times.

I timed it at 1:36 (96 seconds) from OS selection on GRUB to the sign-in screen.
On Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 installations on the same machine, the boot time takes roughly 5 seconds.
I have a new Lenovo laptop with a SSD and 16 GB of RAM, so boot times should be quick (as evidenced by the other Ubuntu boot times).

Swap is being done via a 1 GB swap file mounted on /swapfile.

I have included the output from running `systemd-analyze blame` below.

Note that this shows times that add up to about 24 seconds total, whereas timing it with my watch (i.e., real time) is 96 seconds.

**EDIT:** Adding fstab info

Looking at my fstab file, I see that a boot/efi partition is being mounted.  It is a vfat efi partition from Windows.  Should this even be in the fstab?  Could it be slowing down the boot process?

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=39291b6d-1a32-48c7-9824-c110bf1ea9d6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=B073-D58E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/00bcc125-49df-4760-9350-af2c932eaf71 /home/maddy/Data1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

And the systemd-analyze info:

```
6.641s NetworkManager-wait-online.service             
2.356s plymouth-quit-wait.service                     
979ms snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                   
968ms snap-core18-2066.mount                         
963ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount         
926ms dev-loop1.device                               
890ms dev-loop2.device                                  
829ms dev-loop3.device                               
828ms dev-loop0.device                                     
824ms dev-loop4.device                               
775ms dev-loop5.device                               
729ms dev-loop6.device                               
689ms snapd.service                                  
443ms fwupd.service                                  
322ms systemd-logind.service                         
320ms networkd-dispatcher.service                    
266ms dev-nvme0n1p6.device                           
258ms snap-snapd-9721.mount                          
236ms snap-core18-1997.mount                         
231ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount        
230ms snap-snap\x2dstore-481.mount                   
226ms snap-snapd-11841.mount                         
157ms systemd-journal-flush.service                  
153ms udisks2.service                                
118ms accounts-daemon.service                        
117ms apparmor.service                               
100ms upower.service                                 
 81ms user@1000.service                              
 79ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount         
 76ms systemd-resolved.service                       
 75ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount        
 69ms avahi-daemon.service                           
 67ms systemd-journald.service                       
 67ms NetworkManager.service                         
 67ms bluetooth.service                              
 67ms polkit.service                                 
 63ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                   
 62ms iio-sensor-proxy.service                       
 59ms systemd-rfkill.service                         
 59ms dev-loop8.device                               
 54ms swapfile.swap                                  
 53ms switcheroo-control.service                     
 51ms snapd.apparmor.service                         
 49ms thermald.service                               
 49ms keyboard-setup.service                         
 48ms wpa_supplicant.service                         
 45ms systemd-udevd.service                          
 44ms e2scrub_reap.service                           
 43ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                 
 40ms apport.service                                 
 40ms ModemManager.service                           
 38ms systemd-timesyncd.service                      
 37ms secureboot-db.service                          
 37ms console-setup.service                          
 35ms grub-common.service                            
 31ms plymouth-read-write.service                    
 30ms packagekit.service                             
 28ms dev-loop7.device                               
 27ms gpu-manager.service                            
 24ms snapd.seeded.service                           
 22ms gdm.service                                    
 19ms plymouth-start.service                         
 19ms systemd-modules-load.service                   
 16ms rsyslog.service                                
 16ms dev-loop9.device                               
 14ms home-Data1.mount                        
 12ms modprobe@drm.service                           
 12ms kerneloops.service                             
 11ms colord.service                                 
 11ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                  
 10ms systemd-sysctl.service                         
 10ms dev-hugepages.mount                            
 10ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service             
  9ms alsa-restore.service                           
  9ms pppd-dns.service                               
  9ms dev-mqueue.mount                               
  8ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                         
  8ms systemd-remount-fs.service                     
  8ms systemd-random-seed.service                    
  8ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                       
  8ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service           
  7ms systemd-sysusers.service                       
  7ms systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service 
  7ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                   
  6ms systemd-update-utmp.service                    
  6ms systemd-user-sessions.service                  
  6ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
  5ms kmod-static-nodes.service                      
  4ms rtkit-daemon.service                           
  3ms openvpn.service                                
  3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                  
  3ms sys-kernel-config.mount                        
  3ms ufw.service                                    
  2ms setvtrgb.service                               
  1ms snapd.socket
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and fixing the UUID numbers fixed it. Boot time of Ubuntu mate 20.04 on an SSD was reduced from 1min 40 secs to 15secs.

Go in to fstab file:
`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Note the UUID numbers alongside each partition. Now run this command:
`sudo blkid -o list`

The UUID numbers in this listing should match up with the UUID numbers in /etc/fstab. If they are different change any UUID numbers in /etc/fstab to what their values are in the blkid listing.

Answer (score 1):

As other posts have pointed out, be sure that your UUID numbers in fstab match exactly.  Windows performed some recovery actions that apparently changed the UUID of the partition.  Once this was correctly set in the fstab file, it now boots in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned, You have to edit the `/etc/fstab` and match the UUIDs exactly for your partitions. In my case I did a backup of linux partition with `dd` on one ssd and restored it on another one with a different EFI directory(having changed UUID not present in previous fstab). Matching the UUID reduced the boot time to 3-4 seconds.